# Area of an equilateral triangle with the radii of the inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

Find the area of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with the radii of the inscribed circle $r$.

> The answer given in my book is $3r^2\sqrt3$.

We know that $S=pr$ where $p$ is the semiperimeter and $r$ is the radii of the inscribed circle. How can I express $p$ with $r$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Radius

Comment: In an equilateral $\triangle$, centroid, orthocenter, incenter are the same point. Using this, $p$ and $r$ can be easily related. Or, what are $p$ and $S$ in terms of side of equilateral $\triangle$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE. Since $p = 3a/2$, where $a$ is the length of a side of the triangle, so it suffices to relate $r$ to $a$.

To do this, see the figure [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquilateralTriangle.html) below equation (2). We can make a right triangle with legs of length $a/2$ and $r$, with one angle equal to $30°$. You can now use trigonometry to solve for $a$ in terms of $r$.